# GNOME MPlayer DivX plugin does not work

Tags: mplayer

The Firefox plugin for Totem works for DivX streaming videos, but the GNOME MPlayer one does not, for example for the videos on stagevu.com. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess because of codecs. Follow [this tutoria](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=766683)l and will be able to play everything.

Comment: Hmm, probably not, already installed medibuntu.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a video so I can test it?

Comment: Try stagevu.com, thanks. This problem seems to be quite common when I did an online search. It could be the version of the divx plugin or something like that. In the meantime I'll just use the totem one.

Comment: Works fine here in Firefox 4 and Opera 11.

Comment: Then maybe it is related to my hardware. Thanks a lot for your time!